# The meaning of abstract method?

Tags: java, abstraction

**Edit**: the difference between my question and [What are the differences between abstract classes, interfaces, and when to use them](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/173531/249025), [What are abstract classes and abstract methods?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/179069/249025) is that the chosen answers didn't mention about the compiler-warning part. One even mention the re-use of code by inheritance, which is bad practice actually.

I think what I want to know is beyond the language chosen. But, whatsoever, I means the abstract method in Java. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) of Oracle:

> An *abstract method* is a method that is declared without an implementation (without braces, and followed by a semicolon).

But what I really want to know is the *real purpose* of it, **not just the semantic rules**.

For me, the purpose is that the compiler will tell me what I need to do in the future. Take Eclipse as an example, when I derive a subclass from a abstract class, Eclipse will help me to add all un-implemented methods by one click.

From another point of view, an abstract method will make the super-class-version method, which may have a basic functionality, no longer available, they're *overridden*.(I get this conclusion from decorator pattern.)

Still, all of the above is from my intuition. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: see also [What are the differences between abstract classes, interfaces, and when to use them](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173518/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-classes-interfaces-and-when-to-use-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the purpose is this:

```
public void clientMethod(AbstractType param){
    param.abstractMethod();
}
```

This code is *using* the abstract method without having to know anything about how it's implemented or which class implements it.

The typical example would be the `Comparable` interface, which contains the `compareTo()` method. This allows, for example, [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) to implement a sort algorithm without having to know anything about what it is that it's sorting - just that the abstract method from the interface is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual method *can* be overridden by a subclass if it chooses to, but it doesn't *have* to.  The base class provides a "default" implementation.

An abstract method *must* be overridden by a subclass because the base class cannot or does not provide that "default" implementation.

```
abstract class Person 
{ 
   public string introduction() 
   {
      "I am a " + getSpecies() + " called " + getName() + "."; 
   }

   protected string getSpecies()
   {
      return "human";
   } 

   protected abstract string getName(); 
} 

class FredFlintstone extends Person 
{
   protected string getName()
   {
      return "Fred";
   } 

}

Person person = new FredFlintstone(); 
string hiThere = person.introduction();
```